# Como descobrir versão do android programaticamente?

Tags: android

Sou novo em android e estou precisando pegar a versão do Dispositivo Android de uma forma direta, sem ter que consultar, por exemplo:
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)`

Tem como?

Comment: E porque não pode usar `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a não ser que o AP, em vez do número, queira o nome(HONEYCOMB_MR1)

Comment: Tente Context.getApplicationInfo()

Comment: @ramaral sim pensei nisto, porque se for isto talvez uma lista já resolveria, mas eu não sei se ele quer o codinome ou se ele quer criar códigos fallback para versões mais antigas.

Comment: Peço desculpas a todos. Estive fora por algum tempo e não pude entra neste espaço. Meu problema é o seguinte: Tenho um celular samsung com a versão android "lolipop" 5.0.2. Minha esposa também possui o mesmo celular, porém, comprado mais recente e possui a versão "lolipop" é 5.1.1. Meu App não consegue ler esta versão, já que, usando "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT" , o máximo que consigo é enxergar a versão 5.0.2 (M).